# MATLAB linear equation: what is wrong with this code?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I want to solve this equation to rearrange for `x` but it's giving a message which is strange. Does anyone know what the problem is? I know that the solution is complex but it should still solve for it. I know that my syntax etc are correct. Would anyone know an alternate way to display complex roots?

```
syms x y
eqn = (x^2.5 - (1250*(1-(0.525*x^0.5))^2)/(y*(1-(0.3*x^0.5)))==0)

eqn =
    x^(5/2) + (1250*((21*x^(1/2))/40 - 1)^2)/(y*((3*x^(1/2))/10 - 1)) == 0

v_x=solve(eqn,x)

Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
      z1 = ({0.0} union Dom::ImageSet(1.0*x*I + y, [x, y],  [R_,Dom::Interval(0.0, RD_INF)]) union
      Dom::ImageSet(1.0*x*I, x, Dom::Interval(0.0, RD_INF))) intersect RootOf(48*y*z^6 - 160*y*z^5 + 55125*z^2 -
      210000*z + 200000, z)

> In solve at 190 

v_x =
    z1^2
```

Comment: Maybe try asking on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: you mean to solve for `x` as function of `y`?

Comment: I don't understand how the answer is complex if both `x` and `y` are undefined.  You have an expression where there are two unknowns, so I can't visualize how you would be able to obtain a purely numeric result.  The most you can get is an expression in terms of `y`.

Comment: I tried plotting the solution and you get a quadratic curve i.e. two roots exist but still it should display both the roots.

Comment: Yes to solve for x as a function of y :)

Comment: Then how do you claim the solution is complex if the solution is in terms of y?